# Issue accessing json array because of int

Tags: node.js, arrays

I am having an issue where I cannot access the contents of a json array due to one of the arrays having the name of "0"

I have tried data.0.username and it just shows as red in my editor (the path is 100% correct)

Sorry if this is super basic I couldn't find the same issue online thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Ex if the Json file like data = {0:{'name':'John'},1:{'name':'doe'}}
you can access it with data[0].name or data[1].name